# What is that? Dry brown fungus? See photo please

Tags: species-identification, zoology, botany

[image: dry brown fungus]

It has appeared two days in a row on my balcony, at exactly the same place. There's nothing near that can give me a hint of what it is. The birds can access the place easily. It's an inch in size, it's dry. In the photography you can see a eyelash and some hair, because has been taken after sweeping.

The place is Jerez de la Frontera (Cadiz, Spain).

What it could be? I'm curious and I would like to know why it appears.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please: 1) include the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better), and 2) include habitat information (e.g.s: what types of plants grow nearby and whether you are near water). ——— The location and habitat can be essential clues for identification. Thanks! 

Comment: Looks like bits of insulation. Are birds making a nest above where this appears?

Comment: No, birds aren't making a nest above.